# sub directory links in a site is redirecting to domain link in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, hosting

please visit the link "steel.newtrendzonline.com".

If you click on most of the sub-directory links ,ex: links in menu bar or categories in left , its

redirecting to the domain link http://newtrendzonline.com/steel/ . It was working

fine before.

If you click on "Featured products", it's working fine.

please give me solutioin.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if there are some redirects implemented via htaccess or someother way. Magento is generating correct urls but once you clicked any url it redirects you to http://newtrendzonline.com/steel/

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your reply.

I am new to magento.

Can you help me finding: how to check redirects using "htaccess"?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It would be better if you ask your system/network/linux  admin guy. This file resides in magento root folder.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got htaccess folder. How i can check there about redirects? is it the problem by htaccess file?

Comment: Yes, thereare many chances that redirects are implemented in .htaccess file. I suggest you to check them with your linux admin person.

Comment: Hi, I don't know. after checking the site, without doing any changes, now its working fine.